# VBA Excel - Autofill Method Out of Range Class Error

Tags: vba, excel

I have Autofill Method Out of Range Class Error from some reason and I can't find why. I have lots of formulas in my code and I use it a lot and it is stops my code every time. this is the relavant part of my sub:

```
'U means union, M means main
'Advanced filter for visual worksheet
UnionWB.Worksheets("Union").ShowAllData
Dim ULR As Long, ULC As Long, MLR As Long

ULR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
ULC = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With MainWB.Worksheets(sheet1)
    MLR = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

    MainWB.Worksheets("aheet2").Columns("A:Z").Clear
    UnionWB.Worksheets("Union").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(ULR, ULC)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
    CriteriaRange:=MainWB.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1", "A" & MLR), Unique:=False
    UnionWB.Worksheets("Union").Activate
    Range("A1", "Y" & ULR).Select
    Selection.Copy
    MainWB.Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("AB2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2", "AB" & MLR)


If MLR > 2 Then
    With MainWB.Worksheets("sheet1).Range("N2")
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""sheet2"",RC[-9])),""yes"",""no"")"
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2", "N" & MLR)
    End With
End If
```

> Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2", "AB" & MLR)
>
> Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2", "N" & MLR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the 2 lines below:

```
Range("AB2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2", "AB" & MLR)
```

To:

```
Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & MLR), Type:=xlFillDefault
```